# Obscure ssh connection destination server

Tags: ssh

The content of a ssh connection is pretty secure. However a snooping ISP or network admin can still see where the client's connection is going(aka the server). What is a good way to obscure this information? Is it even possible? Could you run a ssh connection over a socks proxy or tor? (Looking for a free service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using proxy chaining over https. First connection is to google apps api this can be seen by isp/network admin. Then connecting to my server on https(let's encrypt) then my server has a forward proxy running. Details can be found here http://blog.chmd.fr/ssh-over-ssl-a-quick-and-minimal-config.html

Answer (score 0):

A proxy won't hide what you're doing but a VPN would.  That said, the ISP would still see the VPN connection.

Note that most VPNs will log their users' connections even if they say they don't since they will require it for their own protection, because what is done on it would make them responsible unless they can prove it came from someone else.